# Dynamically change less variable for dark theme in Angular

Tags: javascript, css, angular, variables, less

I hope it is possible. Need to dynamically change less variable for using dark theme.
The code is below:

```
@theme: dark;

@colors: {
  primary-violet-light: #608cef;
  primary-violet-dark: #031d58;
}

@primary-violet: @colors[primary-violet-@{theme}]; // have to be #031d58
```

But even it doesn't work. The error is in the last row.

"primary-violet-@{theme}" have to be primary-violet-dark but it doesnt.

Didnt find solution in another topics, so if somebody have a solution for this I would be grateful for help!
Next step is to change @theme variable from app. I use Angular 12.

Comment: less is processed at build time, so you can't change variables "dynamically". You could have two builds with two different outputs or (recommended) you should use [CSS Vars which can be set at runtime](https://css-tricks.com/updating-a-css-variable-with-javascript/)

Comment: @JuanMendes
Thanks a lot! I will try to solve it with css vars.